# How to get values from nested JSON object using jquery?

Tags: jquery, json

I'm trying to create an ajax search using jquery by calling a JSON object. Currently, I'm able to iterate results from an object formatted as follows:

```
[{
    "ID": "4207b2d5b8994bd8a19c28815c07663d",
    "position": 1,
    "voteUpCount": 16,
    "voteDownCount": 32,
    "categories": [{
        "position": 1,
        "category": "7d435c8a70f7447ea03d4cbba11f4686"
    }],
    "keywords": [
        "key-word"
    ],
    "title": "This is a title",
    "body": "<p>this is description</p>",
    "outdated": false,
    "slug": "this-is-an-article",
    "views": 0,
    "labelName": [
        ""
    ],
    "locale": "gb",
    "storeName": "mystore",
    "id": 4207
},{
    "ID": "4207b2d5b8994bd8a19c28815c07663d",
    "position": 1,
    "voteUpCount": 16,
    "voteDownCount": 32,
    "categories": [{
        "position": 1,
        "category": "7d435c8a70f7447ea03d4cbba11f4686"
    }],
    "keywords": [
        "key-word"
    ],
    "title": "This is a title",
    "body": "<p>this is description</p>",
    "outdated": false,
    "slug": "this-is-an-article",
    "views": 0,
    "labelName": [
        ""
    ],
    "locale": "gb",
    "storeName": "mystore",
    "id": 4207
} ]
```

I can build my results using the following:

```
$.each(data, function(key, value){
        article_data += '<div class="faq-item" data-artcile><a href="#">'+ value.title +'</a><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></div>'; 
        article_data += '<div class="faq-answer">'+ value.body +'</div>';
    });
```

The problem I have is that my production JSON object comes in wrapped in a response, like this:

```
    {
    "response": [{
    "ID": "4207b2d5b8994bd8a19c28815c07663d",
    "position": 1,
    "voteUpCount": 16,
    "voteDownCount": 32,
    "categories": [{
        "position": 1,
        "category": "7d435c8a70f7447ea03d4cbba11f4686"
    }],
    "keywords": [
        "key-word"
    ],
    "title": "This is a title",
    "body": "<p>this is description</p>",
    "outdated": false,
    "slug": "this-is-an-article",
    "views": 0,
    "labelName": [
        ""
    ],
    "locale": "gb",
    "storeName": "mystore",
    "id": 4207
},{
    "ID": "4207b2d5b8994bd8a19c28815c07663d",
    "position": 1,
    "voteUpCount": 16,
    "voteDownCount": 32,
    "categories": [{
        "position": 1,
        "category": "7d435c8a70f7447ea03d4cbba11f4686"
    }],
    "keywords": [
        "key-word"
    ],
    "title": "This is a title",
    "body": "<p>this is description</p>",
    "outdated": false,
    "slug": "this-is-an-article",
    "views": 0,
    "labelName": [
        ""
    ],
    "locale": "gb",
    "storeName": "mystore",
    "id": 4207
} ],
    "http_code": 200
}
```

So the code I'm using to build my resulting HTML doesn't work, cause it can't find the KEYS I'm targeting in my loop.

The question is: **How can I iterate through this wrapped object correctly?**

I have tried using, for example, this format without success

```
value.response.title
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The structure is identical, the array is just within the `response` property now, so add it in: `$.each(data.response, function() { ... `

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, thanks that is exactly the right solution. It works like a charm now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All data having in response variable 'data.response'.

```
$.each(data.response, function(key, value){
        article_data += '<div class="faq-item" data-artcile><a href="#">'+ value.title +'</a><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></div>'; 
        article_data += '<div class="faq-answer">'+ value.body +'</div>';
});
```